How to Stop reloading the web when pressing enter in React
I am currently doing a simple to-do list, and I have a problem that when I click enter, my web will reload, which I expect will be adding a new task.
Thank you for helping.
handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (!this.state.input) {
      alert("You need to write a task!");
      return;
    }
    this.props.addNewTask({
      id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000 + 1),
      value: this.state.input,
    });
    this.setState({ showAddTask: false, input: "" });
  };

  handleKeyDown = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
      this.handleSubmit(event);
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="main-add-task">
        {this.state.showAddTask ? (
          <form className="add-task-form">
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="Do homework at 3pm"
              onChange={this.handleChangeInput}
              autoFocus
            />
            <div className="change-button">
              <button type="button" onClick={this.handleCancel}>
                Cancel
              </button>
              <button type="button" onClick={this.handleSubmit}>
                Add task
              </button>
            </div>
          </form>
        ) : (
          <button onClick={this.handleShow}>Add Task</button>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default AddTask;

i tried to add event.preventDefault();to my 2 functions

The submit function should be an onSubmit prop of your <form/> element. The button with "type="submit" will automatically submit the form, calling that function. Then the event.preventDefault(); will work, cos the event is coming from the form itself

The main problem in this code is the handleKeyDown method.
You're currently using event.preventDefault(), which prevents default submissions when the Enter key is pressed. Then you're calling the handleSubmit() function.
A better way to handle form submissions can be:
handleSubmit = (event) => {
  // Prevent default form submission (page reload) whic you're already doing
  event.preventDefault();
  
  if (!this.state.input) {
    alert("You need to write a task!");
    return;
  }
  
  this.props.addNewTask({
    id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000 + 1),
    value: this.state.input,
  });
  
  this.setState({ showAddTask: false, input: "" });
};

render() {
  return (
    <div className="main-add-task">
      {this.state.showAddTask ? (
        <form 
          className="add-task-form" 
          onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}  // Add this line
        >
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Do homework at 3pm"
            onChange={this.handleChangeInput}
            value={this.state.input}  // add this to make it a controlled component
            autoFocus
          />
          <div className="change-button">
            <button type="button" onClick={this.handleCancel}>
              Cancel
            </button>
            <button type="submit">  {/* change to type="submit" */}
              Add task
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>
      ) : (
        <button onClick={this.handleShow}>Add Task</button>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}


Another update I would look into is using hooks (useState / etc). class based / this.X --- can become confusing from my point of view
